# Linking myQ garage door to IFTTT

Tags: smart-home, ifttt

I have managed to close my myQ garage door (a LiftMaster) (by Chamberlain Group) using IFTTT. Here's the setup

- myQ app on an iPhone
- IFTTT app on an iPhone
- myQ account subscribed to IFTTT
- the garage door, of course

When setting up the IFTTT trigger and action, the actions available when searching for and selecting myQ presents 3 options

- Turn off light
- Turn on light
- Close door

There is no "Open door". Selecting "Close door" identifies my garage door as an option, and the trigger works when the door is already open.

Because there is no "Open door", I tried to use the same trigger when the door was closed to open the door (hoping this was a toggle rather than an explicit option) but this did not work.

Are there any options here? It seems like this is an issue on the IFTTT side of things, but I am not sure.

Comment: Assuming you have a security+ 2.0 door opener, have a look at the new shield I released for controlling these doors. I implemented discrete open/close commands. https://paulwieland.github.io/ratgdo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was intentionally omitted for security reason, you do not want anyone (hacker or intruder when integrated with other smart home like Alexa and others) to open the door.

Comment: If it was intentionally omitted, how is it that SimpleCommands can OPEN a door?

Comment: @JohnI SimpleCommands probably just issues a "button press" which toggles the garage door state, much like the button in your car or on your wall.